# How to set the jolokia context path in springboot admin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

1. I set the application service management.context-path to /mgmt and Registry it to eureka server.

`eureka:
  instance:
    statusPageUrlPath: ${management.context-path}/info
    healthCheckUrlPath: ${management.context-path}/health
    metadata-map:
      management.context-path: ${management.context-path}
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://registry:7000/eureka/`

2. when i view the JMX in admin UI(another different service, and registry in eureka server), i got some security issue. and actually i add the /mgmt/* to the white list

`http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/" ,"/mgmt/*","/jolokia","/jolokia/**").permitAll()`

How to set the jolokia context path in springboot admin?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh F**k, just a mistake, change the /mgmt/* to /mgmt/**, it works.

`http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/" , "/mgmt/**","/jolokia","/jolokia/**").permitAll()`